# How to determine the version of Glassfish's dependencies?

Tags: jersey, glassfish, dependencies, version

I'm working on a project that incorporates some Jersey dependencies not packaged with Glassfish and need to know what version of Jersey Glassfish 4.1.1 is using.

In the Glassfish Maven pom.xml, here
https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/main/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/4.1.1/glassfish-embedded-all-4.1.1.pom, there is a reference to Jersey:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.packager</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>zip</type>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Which is actually a reference to the Jersey version embedded in Glassfish, here https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/main/packager/jersey/4.1.1/jersey-4.1.1.pom.

So from my understanding, Glassfish copies its dependencies at the time they are included into its own repository without retaining version information. How do I get that version information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Updating Jersey 2 in GlassFish 4](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/), two options mentioned are to:

1. Just unzip one of the Jersey jars e.g. (`jersey-common`) and look at the `Bundle-Version` in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. You can find the jars in `<glassfish-home>/glasssfish/modules`
2. Just start up the server, with a JAX-RS application running and
   log

   ```
   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.5.1 2014-01-02 13:43:00...]]
   ```